# Chrome browser doesn't find Chromecast audio device

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

How can I cast from Chrome browser to a Chromecast audio form Windows 10?

Chromecast only finds my Chromcast video devices but no Chromecast audio.

Answer (score 0):

In the address bar of Chrome browser enter

`chrome://flags/` and `enable`

- Cast Media Route Provider
- Connect to Cast devices on all IP addresses
- Load Media Router Component Extension
- WebRTC new encode cpu load estimator

and reboot, if the Chromecast audio is still not listed.